# How to add a link to a geography (created as a json path) in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a simple map of NYC boroughs in d3.js. I'd like to add a link to each borough, but I can't figure out how to do so.

Below is the code I have right now-- there's just a placeholder link to the New York Times website. However, it's adding the `<a href>` inside of the `<path>` tag, which doesn't work. How can I attach a link? Is this possible?

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
    #boroughs {
      stroke: none;
        stroke-width: 0px;
        fill: #ddd;
        opacity:.7;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

    <body>
    <script>

    // map
    var width = Math.max(960, window.innerWidth),
        height = Math.max(500, window.innerHeight);

    var container = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("id", "container")
            .style("width", width + "px")
            .style("height", height + "px");

    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
            .center([-73.94, 40.70])
            .scale(80000)
            .translate([(width) / 2, (height)/2]);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);

    d3.json("nyc.json", function(error, nyb) {

    var map = container.append("svg")
            .attr("id", "boroughs")
            .style("width", width + "px")
            .style("height", height + "px")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(nyb.features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d){ return d.properties.borough; })
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.nytimes.com");
    });


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways to add links to SVG shapes:

1. Use of the `<svg:a>` element. As you have already stated in your question, this won't work if it is nested within the element to which the link should be added. Much like the element of the same name in HTML, you need to wrap the `<a>` around the content which should have the link attached.

   ```
   var map = container.append("svg")
           .attr("id", "boroughs")
           .style("width", width + "px")
           .style("height", height + "px")
         .selectAll("path")
           .data(nyb.features)
           .enter()
           .append("a")                                     // The link goes here...
             .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.nytimes.com")                                     
           .append("path")                                  // ...wrapping the path.
             .attr("class", function(d){
               return d.properties.borough;
             })
             .attr("d", path);
   ```
2. As laid out in [Cyril's answer](http:///a/34716777/4235784) you could attach a JavaScript event listener handling `click` events.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a click listener to the path and open the window like this `var win = window.open(YOUR_URL, "_blank")`:

```
var map = container.append("svg")
        .attr("id", "boroughs")
        .style("width", width + "px")
        .style("height", height + "px")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(nyb.features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d){ return d.properties.borough; })
        .attr("d", path)
        .on("click", function(d){var win = window.open(YOUR_URL, "_blank"); win.focus();});
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"_self"` instead of `"_blank"`? I can't find any hint to open it in a new tab/window.

Comment: _blank opens up in a new tab _self opens up in the current window http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp.

Comment: Exactly! My comment was just that OP nowhere asked for a new window or window.

Comment: yeah u r right may be OP need to clarify what he wish to do with the link.... i ll delete my answer then Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!